# Plugin Jquery slide

Tags: jquery, plugin

Este js faz toda parte de next,prev e auto do meu slide, mas há um "porém": quando eu clico em prev, ele volta e depois avança na mesma ação.

O que tem de errado na lógica deste script?

JS:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#myCarousel').carousel({
        interval:   4000
    });

    var clickEvent = false;
    $('#myCarousel').on('click', '.nav a', function() {
            clickEvent = true;
            $('.nav li').removeClass('active');
            $(this).parent().addClass('active');        
    }).on('slid.bs.carousel', function(e) {
        if(!clickEvent) {
            var count = $('.nav').children().length -1;
            var current = $('.nav li.active');
            current.removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
            var id = parseInt(current.data('slide-to'));
            if(count == id) {
                $('.nav li').first().addClass('active');    
            }
        }
        clickEvent = false;
    });
        $(document).ready(function(){

                $(".prev-slide").click(function(){
                var count = $('.nav').children().length -1;
                var current = $('.nav li.active');
                current.removeClass('active').prev().addClass('active');
                    var id = parseInt(current.data('slide-to'));
    });
    });
 });
```

HTML:

```
 <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"><a href="#">INTERCAMBIO</a></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"><a href="#">AÉREO</a></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"><a href="#">PHENOMENAL</a></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"><a href="#">CURSOS</a></li>
            </ul>
```

Comment: pq tem um $(document).ready() dentro de outro?

Comment: Qual é o `carousel` que estás a usar? não tem métodos para fazer mudar as imagens sem teres de fazer à mão?

Comment: Sim, mas eu quero que os controladores fiquem com um background quando a imagem passar, é tipo um active.. mas não estou conseguindo..

Comment: Eu não manjo muito de jquery, tentei adaptar, mas acho que não funfou direito.. algo referente á isso que estou tentando fazer..http://imgur.com/XwZqyqA

Comment: Olá, coloque seu código no site www.bootply.com, assim podemos ajudá-lo melhor

Answer (score 0):

Em HTML, adicione  `id="myCarousel"` no `<ul id="myCarousel" class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">`, que deve ficar assim: `<ul id="myCarousel" class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">`.

Também removi a duplicidade de dois `$(document).ready`.

Além disso, seu trecho de código (snippet) não mostrava a chamada ao Jquery e ao Bootstrap, também incluí para ficar completamente funcional o exemplo.

O código final ficou assim:

```js
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#myCarousel').carousel({
     interval:   4000
 });
 
 var clickEvent = false;
 $('#myCarousel').on('click', '.nav a', function() {
     clickEvent = true;
  $('.nav li').removeClass('active');
  $(this).parent().addClass('active');  
 }).on('slid.bs.carousel', function(e) {
  if(!clickEvent) {
      var count = $('.nav').children().length -1;
   var current = $('.nav li.active');
   current.removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
   var id = parseInt(current.data('slide-to'));
   if(count == id) {
    $('.nav li').first().addClass('active'); 
   }
  }
  clickEvent = false;
 });
       
    $(".prev-slide").click(function(){
        var count = $('.nav').children().length -1;
        var current = $('.nav li.active');
        current.removeClass('active').prev().addClass('active');
        var id = parseInt(current.data('slide-to'));
    });
 
 
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<ul id="myCarousel" class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"><a href="#">INTERCAMBIO</a></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"><a href="#">AÉREO</a></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"><a href="#">PHENOMENAL</a></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"><a href="#">CURSOS</a></li>
</ul>
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Se esta resposta foi útil para você, não se esqueça de marcá-la como útil (+1).